# Checking 2 Column for Duplicate

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, optimization, database-design

Currently, I have a system to hold main data

1) The email

2) The owner(user_id)

Every time someone uploads , I need to make sure that it doesn't not exist in the system. The catch is as I upload more and more, the amount of time taken to check for duplicate will grow steeply, just like the graph as shown.

Question

1) How do i check for duplicate efficiently?

2) I indexed the user_id and the email should I Fulltext it? I wont be reading the text but will be searching for it as a whole, so index is more logical?

3) I also read about creating Hash combining email&owner id then index the hash. Will it be a big difference from the current method?

4) Last method i thought of was to create a primary key for both email and user_id , once again idk how the performance would turn out.

Please advice.

Code

```
$exist = DB::table('contact')->where('email', $row['email'])->where('user_id', $user_id)->count();
            if($exist < 1){
              DB::table('contact')->insert(
                ['email' => $row['email'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'user_id' => $user_id]
              );
              }
```

[image]

Comment: Use INSERT IGNORE, in case the INSERT fails silently LAST_INSERT_ID will be 0 ,AFAIK. Add an unqiue index on both columns

Comment: so show your db schema and your query!?

Comment: @Alex, using laravel not raw query. So it's basically , as described check both column (two Wheres), I can also use Raw query if required for Laravel if you have any theory to support the usage of it.

Comment: using laravel you have finally the query executed. but even if you can't find the query itself, you can provide the laravel code. nobody can help with virtual code :-) and db schema is still actual

Comment: @Alex I get your point, added, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel Validator:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_id' => 'required|unique',
        'email' => 'required|unique',
]);
//some logic here
}
```

Also you should use `unique` constraint in your database.